# ACF Group Sub Field Not Displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created custom fields through the ACF Options page where a user will input their social media profile links. If there is no link, it will not display that icon on the front end. I've done this through creating a group titled 'Social Media' with the various platforms as fields within that group.

I'm pulling my hair out trying to pull those sub-field values into the theme footer. It simply doesn't display anything but when I display a value that isn't nested within a group it shows up.

**Footer.php ↴**

```
<?php
   if( have_rows('social_media') ):
   while( have_rows('social_media') ) : the_row();
?>
<li>
   <a href="<?php the_sub_field('instagram'); ?>">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/icons/instagram.png" width="25px" height="25px" alt="Instagram Profile">
   </a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

**ACF Group ↴**

[image: ACF Group]

**ACF Options Page ↴**

[image: ACF Options Page]

TIA for any help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the fields are on an ACF options page so you have to pass the string **options** in the **have_rows** function

```
have_rows('social_media', 'options')
```

Check this link for more info https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/

the code wil look like:

```
<?php
   if( have_rows('social_media', 'option') ):
   while( have_rows('social_media', 'option') ) : the_row();
?>
<li>
   <a href="<?php the_sub_field('instagram'); ?>">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/icons/instagram.png" width="25px" height="25px" alt="Instagram Profile">
   </a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

*Note that the sub fields don't need a options string*

A clean way to hide the Li when the field is empty:

```
<?php while ( have_rows('social_media', 'option') ) : the_row(); ?>
    <?php if (get_sub_field('instagram')): ?>
        <li>
           <a href="<?php the_sub_field('instagram'); ?>">
              <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/icons/instagram.png" width="25px" height="25px" alt="Instagram Profile">
           </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much! With this code, whats the best approach for an if...while...else statement to hide the LI if there is no link?

Comment: Nice! i edited my answer with a solution to hide the Li when the field is empty

Answer (score 1):

If you have created this field in options page then you have to pass `option` parameter with the field. Check this link https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/

Like this

```
<?php the_field('your-field-name', 'option'); ?>
```

So try with below code.

```
<?php
   if( have_rows('social_media', 'option') ):
   while( have_rows('social_media', 'option') ) : the_row();
?>
<li>
   <a href="<?php the_sub_field('instagram'); ?>">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/icons/instagram.png" width="25px" height="25px" alt="Instagram Profile">
   </a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you echo fields from ACF Options Page, just pass 'option' parameter like the_field('acf_field_name', 'option' )

In your case code should be:

```
<?php
if( have_rows('social_media', 'option') ):
   while( have_rows('social_media', 'option') ) : the_row();
?>
<li>
   <a href="<?php the_sub_field('instagram'); ?>">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/icons/instagram.png" width="25px" height="25px" alt="Instagram Profile">
   </a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```